# What Roles and/or Permissions would I need to Assign to Users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to have certain users of an Sql Server database to be able to:

- Create Logins
- Create Users in databases
- Assign insert, update, select and delete permissions on certain tables within that database

What roles or permissions do I need to assign to them to accomplish this?

I've searched many online articles that offered vague explanations but found no direct answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Create Logins:**
User needs to be part of the `LoginManager` Group to `Create` / `Alter` a Login. Also, they need to have *ALTER ANY LOGIN* Permission:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO user1
```

**Create Users in databases**
User needs to have *ALTER ANY USER* permission to create user.

```
GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO user1
```

**Assign insert, update, select and delete permissions on certain tables within that database**
User needs to have *`SELECT` / `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE`* Permission on specific object.

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Tabela TO users1
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.Tabela TO users1
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.Tabela TO users1
GRANT DELETE ON dbo.Tabela TO users1
```

Comment: What is a "LoginManager Group"? What rights/permissions do people have who are members of this group?